# Tapable.plugin is deprecated

Tags: webpack, node-modules, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

How can I get webpack/encore to run?

**yarn run encore dev --watch**

```
yarn run v1.10.1
$ /var/www/html/symfony-dev/node_modules/.bin/encore dev --watch
Running webpack ...


webpack is watching the files…

(node:6631) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
/var/www/html/symfony-dev/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:827
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (/var/www/html/symfony-dev/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:827:9)
```

**Versions**

```
yarn - v1.10.1
webpack - 3.5.6
extract-text-webpack-plugin - 4.0.0-beta.0
npm - 6.4.1
node - v10.10.0

Ubuntu 18.04 - Bionic Beaver
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
        // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
        .setOutputPath('public/build/')
        // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
        .setPublicPath('/build')
        .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
        .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
        .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
        // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
        //.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
        .enableVueLoader()
        //.enableSassLoader()
        ;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig(
        {
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            devServer: {
                contentBase: './dist'
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        use: [
                            'style-loader',
                            'css-loader'
                        ]
                    }
                ]

            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried updating to Webpack 4 ? the plugins api was changed then, so maybe the author of the plugin triggering that error did the same

Comment: Tried that, thanks.  Still trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

Environment - Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7, symfony 4.x

Used npm to install packages until everything would run.  Started with webpack 3.5.6

**Commands**

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
yarn cache clean
npm install webpack@3.5.6
npm install @symfony/webpack-encore --save-dev
npm i vue vue-template-compiler vue-template vue-loader
npm i babel-loader
npm i @babel/core --save-dev
npm i bootstrap-vue
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin
npm i bootstrap
npm install --save
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.17.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "clean-self-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-template": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```